# getting error Parsing error: Expression expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I am getting error:

> Parsing error: Expression expected

Here is my code base:

```
    export interface TableRow {
      rowKey: string;
      rowCells: {[key: string]: any};
      rowExpanded?: React.ReactNode;
    }
class MvSortTable extends React.Component<Props, State> {
 ...
      toggleAllRows = () => {
        const shouldExpand = this.allRowsCollapsed(this.state.expandedRows);
        const expandedRows: {[key: string]: boolean} = {};
    
        this.props.rows?.forEach((row) => {
         expandedRows[row.rowKey] = shouldExpand;
        });
    
        this.setState({ expandedRows, allRowsCollapsed: !shouldExpand });
      }
...
```

Error come from when I add `?` into `this.props.rows...`

How can I fix this error?????

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem related to:

- your installed TypeScript compiler version (see [Typescript optional chaining error: Expression expected.ts(1109)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54611471/typescript-optional-chaining-error-expression-expected-ts1109))

OR

- some Prettier/ESlint extensions related issue (see [Angular: Expression expected in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71249797/angular-expression-expected-in-vscode))

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is facing this issue you might want to check the `eslint-plugin-prettier` in your `package.json`.

I recently stumbled upon this issue and I found that the project I was working on was on the older version.

Just upgrade `eslint-plugin-prettier`, at the time of writing this the latest version is `4.0.0`

Cheers!!

Comment: In case someone runs into this: I was actually using prettier in a nextjs by itself and this caused the issue for some reason. Switched to eslint-plugin-prettier as recommended 
https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint

Fixed my issue related unexpected "Expression expected" errors