# How do I resolve TypeScript optional chaining error "TS1109: Expression expected" in VS Code?

Tags: typescript, npm, discord.js, nodemon

Just for some background I'm creating a discord bot using discord.js. I'm currently following this [video guide](https://youtu.be/pXehoXnFxPM?t=235) (linked at the timestamp where I'm having an issue) and I've copied exactly what has been done up until that point.

Here are the versions of everything I'm using:

- VS Code: 1.65.2
- Node: 16.14.2
- npm: 8.5.0
- TypeScript: 4.6.2
- dotenv: 16.0.0
- discord.js: 13.6.0
- nodemon: 2.0.15

I'll put my code and errors below but also here's a SrcShare: [SrcShare Link](https://srcshare.io/?id=62391987237093507ca1a16c)

**index.ts**

```
import DiscordJS, { Intents } from 'discord.js'
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()

const client = new DiscordJS.Client({
    intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES
    ],
})

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('The bot is ready.')

    const guildId = '276237909378465794'
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(guildId)
    let commands

    if (guild) {
        commands = guild.commands
    } else {
        commands = client.application?.commands
    }

    commands?.create({
        name: 'ping',
        description: 'Replies with pong.',
    })
})

client.login(process.env.TOKEN)
```

**Errors I get when running `ts-node index.ts` in the terminal**

```
return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes)
       ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
index.ts(22,39): error TS1109: Expression expected.
index.ts(23,5): error TS1005: ':' expected.
index.ts(25,14): error TS1109: Expression expected.
index.ts(29,1): error TS1005: ':' expected.

[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I've tried the solutions from this other [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54611471/typescript-optional-chaining-error-expression-expected-ts1109) where the problem also seems to be optional chaining with the `?` operator. All of the solutions in that thread say you need to update to TypeScript 3.7+ where optional chaining is supported but I'm using TypeScript 4.6.2.

If anyone knows what's going on here I'd appreciate the help!

**UPDATE**

So I think this might be a problem with nodemon. If I run `ts-node index.ts` in terminal the bot starts up without errors. But in the `package.json` I have a script that looks like this `"dev": "nodemon index.ts"`. When I run `npm run dev` I still get the errors shown above even though nodemon should just be running `ts-node index.ts`.

Comment: If it works with `tsc` and successfully transpiles your `ts-node` is probably outdated - use `npm outdated` and check (or just update it anyways to be safe).

Comment: I just started getting this error too, and updating `ts-node` did not help. Working on this now, so if I find a solution I'll put up an answer.

Comment: Btw, my problem is not with nodemon, I'm seeing this compilation error on my own code.

Answer (score 3):

Check the `node_modules` folder to see if you are *actually* using the version of TypeScript you think you're using. My issue was that a package I was depending on was depending on TypeScript 3.4.3 and installing that version in my project's `node_modules` folder.

Updating the package to one that didn't specify the TypeScript version it relies on fixed it for me.

Comment: In my case, I forgot to install Typescript (it is a `devDependencies`) during building docker image.